# Selecting drop down value using Selenium Webdriver using Node js

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

Hi I am trying to create automated test with selenium webdriver using Nodejs
I am having problem selecting value from drop down menu
My code to select value from drop down is

```
   await driver.findElement(By.name('state')).getText(5).cllick();
```

Basically there is a dropdown of all the states and I am trying to read the 5th state in the drop down. When I run this I can see dropdown to expand but nothing happens after that.
Please let me know how I can read the state value from dropdown.

The code for drop down is

select
AK
.......

Comment: Can you show the HTML?

Comment: Please add the HTML code  for dropdown.

Comment: Added the drop down code

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
Select dd = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("your identifier")));
dd.selectByVisibleText("5");
```

You can also choose by index or value.

Comment: the questions was regarding selenium bindings for nodejs